# Subsonic 3 - Sequence contains no matching element

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I need help creating a LINQ SQL with subsonic. First the basics, this works fine:

```
var query = (from o in bd.concelhos
                     orderby o.descricao
                     select o);

        var results = query.ToList<concelhos>();
```

However, I want to filter out some columns and I have created the following code:

```
var query = (from o in bd.concelhos
                     orderby o.descricao
                     select new FilteredConcelhos { id = o.idDistrito + "/" + o.idConcelho, descricao = o.descricao });

        var results = query.ToList<FilteredConcelhos>();
```

which errors out in the ToList method with the description "Sequence contains no matching element"

Any help would be great with this...

**update**:
Turns out I was missing get set attributes in the newly declared class...
Like so

```
public class FilteredConcelhos
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }
}
```

This clears the exception, but the resulting List is still all wrong (FilteredConcelhos.id contains nothing and FilteredConcelhos.descricao contains numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to first execute the ToList and the select afterwards - then the select is performed via linq 2 objects!

Comment: Can you provide some code? How is it possible to first execute the ToList and then the select?

Comment: Try something like this:

var query = (from o in bd.concelhos
                     orderby o.descricao
                     select o);

        var results = query.ToList().Select(o => new FilteredConcelhos { id = o.idDistrito + "/" + o.idConcelho, descricao = o.descricao });

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to work with an anonymous type?

```
var query = (from o in bd.concelhos
                 orderby o.descricao
                 select new { id = o.idDistrito + "/" + o.idConcelho, 
                              descricao = o.descricao });

var results = query.ToList();
```

Comment: problem is that I want to return results back. How can I return an anonymous type?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this happened to me a lot. I'm not sure about the details of how Linq 2 Object works, but if you'll call ToList on the original object, like this:

```
from o in bd.concelhos.ToList()
...
```

It should do the trick.